# Добавить id к ссылке

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток.
Не могу никак разобраться, как при помощи скрипта добавить id к ссылке.

К примеру есть
`<a href="/data"></a>`

И у этой ссылке нужно добавить id 'day'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("id", "day");
```

Попробуйте таким методом.

Comment: @РоманМереняну-Ени, тогда можно обращаться как к элементу массива. Добавил в ответе

Comment: @РоманМереняну-Ени, первый вариант вообще не сработал бы, была бы ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
document.querySelector("a[href='/data']").setAttribute("id","day");
```